# what is protection rate difference between cellular pentavac and acellular pentamaxim vaccination?

Tags: vaccination

I got first 2 doses of vaccination of  cellular DPT vaccine vaccine from government hospital, both caused intense irritability and fever to about 103 degree to my 3 month kid.

A different doctor of private hospital told that there is acellular pentamaxim vaccination injection that is painless, however I also got to know that protection rate of acellular pantavlent is less than the other one which is painful.

what is protection rate difference between cellular pentavac and acellular pentamaxim vaccination ?